# sencha cmd extjs build does not include MVC controllers

Tags: extjs, cmd, extjs4.1

When I 'compile' my extjs MVC app (version 4.1.1a, CMD ver 3.0.2.288), an **all-classes.js** file gets created however none of my custom code (controllers, views etc) gets included.  They get dynamically loaded when I load the html page.  I have another app that works fine.  I can't post my hundreds of lines of code.  What can I look for?

I tried the CMD build in debug mode and it seems to process and find all my app files, it just doesn't include in all-classes.js.

I tried

```
    sencha -d app build
```

and

```
    sencha compile -classpath=app/app.js,app,ext/src  page -in=index.html -out=build/index.html
```

I used 'sencha generate app' to create the original directory structure etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why but it seems if I explicitly do a 'requires' on my controllers in my app.js file then the compile works

```
 Ext.Loader.setConfig({ enabled: true });
 Ext.require([
     'AM.controller.myController1'
   , 'AM.controller.myController2'
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same issue.
Maybe as a hint, I've got another project where I generated the whole application, and the build. And here, with the build-impl.xml, I've got everything I need in all-classes : my controllers, models, etc